# Fix sort-keys ESLint rule in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I am using Visual Studio Code for my front end development. I have enabled the `sort-keys` rule which requires the keys of all object to be in alphabetical order.
I came to find out that neither ESLint, nor Prettier supports autofixing it, due to potential bugs the auto-fix can introduce, thus both of them has rejected the proposal to even consider adding auto-fix as option.

Now I have a very large legacy code base where I just added ESLint, and I need this sort-keys rule in the project. Is there any way I can auto-fix them provided I know what am I doing, possibly through some VSCode plugin or a custom script?
I am sure that changing the order of the keys will not affect my code negatively. I need it for both JSON objects as well as JS object literals.

Comment: `I need it for both JSON objects as well as JS object literals.` - Note that [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). If you have an object or array, then you have an object or array, full stop. JSON format is a *method of representing an object in a string*, like `const myJSON = '{"foo":"bar"}'`. Ordering keys of a plain object is quite different from (and probably a lot easier) than rearranging portions of a string which happen to be in JSON format

Comment: You might be able to integrate the [rejected pull request](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/7715/files) which says it makes sort-keys fixable

Comment: @CertainPerformance I meant objects in .json file, as well as objects with functions as the values of keys in JS files. I am checking the pull request to see if I can integrate it. I need to pass it down to my teammates too so need to keep the steps to install, as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an automated solution but it helps with sorting object keys manually during development.

[Sort JS object keys](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zengxingxin.sort-js-object-keys) VS Code plugin

1. Install the plugin
2. Select an object in the code, including outer `{` and `}`. Hint: expand selection keyboard shortcut ⌃⇧⌘→ is helpful for this.
3. Run "Sort JS object keys" command.

Comment: perfect what I was looking for!